# Hash destructuring in Ruby 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I Ruby 2 you could do the following:

```rb
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ab: 2, ac: 3}}

my_hash.each do |key, aa:, ab: 4, **|
  puts key
  puts aa
  puts ab
end
```

In Ruby 3 this now results in `missing keywords :aa, :ab`. What would be the best way to refactor code like this in Ruby 3?

Something like the following would not work because it doesn't support setting default values:

```rb
my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values in {aa: aa, ab: ab}
end
```

The best way I can think of is putting the existing code in a wrapper:

```rb
lambda = ->(key, aa:, ab: 4, **) do
  puts key
  puts aa
  puts ab
end

my_hash.each do |key, values|
  lambda.call(key, **values)
end
```

Any better options?

Comment: you can use the fact if we access any key which not exists in hash it return `nil`, for eg: check [here](https://ideone.com/pHYtm5).

Answer (score 7):

I can't think of a way to convert the hash to keyword arguments.

But why not use the hash the way it is, i.e. without treating its keys like keywords? Unless your actual code is more complex, [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#fetch-method) seems to do what you want:

```
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ab: 2, ac: 3}}

my_hash.each do |key, values|
  puts key
  puts values.fetch(:aa)
  puts values.fetch(:ab, 4)
end
```

The above works fine in both, Ruby 2 and 3. Just like your example, it will raise an error if `:aa` is missing and it will use a default value of `4` if `:ab` is missing.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to use default value but need just destruct hash, you can use `=>` operator for [pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html)

```
my_hash = { a: { aa: 1, ab: 2, ac: 3 } }

my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values => { aa:, ab:, ac: }

  puts key, aa, ab, ac
end
```

This code will raise `NoMatchingPatternKeyError` if `values` don't include all keys

Answer (score 2):

#### with `||`

> As stated by @Stefan it will not works if the value can contains `nil` or `false`

```
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ac: 3}}
 
my_hash.each do |key, values|
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values[:ab] || 4
end
```

#### with [`key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F)

```
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ac: 3}}
default_values_hash = { :ab => 4 }
 
my_hash.each do |key, values|
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values.key?(:ab) ? values[:ab] : default_values_hash[:ab]
end
```

#### with [`default`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-default)

```rb
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ab: 2, ac: 3}}

my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values.default = :notfound
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values[:ab] == :notfound ? 4 : values[:ab]
end
```

```rb
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ac: 3}}
 
my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values.default = :notfound
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values[:ab] == :notfound ? 4 : values[:ab]
end
```

#### with [`default-proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc)

```rb
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ab: 2, ac: 3}}
default_values_hash = { :ab => 4 }

my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values.default_proc = proc { |hash, key| default_values_hash[key] || :notfound }
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values[:ab]
end
```

#### with [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
my_hash = {a: {aa: 1, ac: 3}}
default_values_hash = { :ab => 4 }
 
my_hash.each do |key, values|
  values = default_values_hash.merge(values)
  puts key
  puts values[:aa]
  puts values[:ab]
end
```

All above code works in both Ruby 2 and 3

**Note:**
I would suggest the `key?` method to test and check if key exists and handle the case accordingly as it would be much faster as comparing to other cases which require additional steps internally.

Comment: Keep in mind that `||` only works if the hash value can’t be `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

We can assign each value to a variable and check if it is hash or not then we can print the values again in inner loop

```
my_hash = {a: { aa: 1, ab: 2, ac:3 }}
may_hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  if value.kind_of(Hash)
    value.each do |inner_key, inner_value|
      puts inner_key
      puts inner_value
    end
  else
    puts value
  end
end
```

In this we can refactor outer hash and inner hash at same time.